# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function

Tags: php, php7

Estoy haciendo una web a base de PHP puro y tengo un problema con la paginación, el error es el siguiente:

**Fatal error**: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_pagination() on array in C:\xampp\htdocs\Blog-php\index.php:13 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Blog-php\index.php on **line 13**

estoy confundido ya que solo hago llamado a una función que viene de un objeto `Articles`, el codigo es el siguiente:

funcion del objeto `Articles`

```
public function get_pagination(){
$PPP = 5;
$conn = new Connection ();
$totalArticles = $conn->query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as total');
$totalArticles =  $totalArticles->fetch()['total'];

$n_Page = ceil($totalArticles / $PPP);

return $n_Page;

}
```

Luego llamo a la clase en el `index.php`

```
$articles = new Article('','','','','');
$articles = $articles->get_articles($page);
$n_Page = $articles->get_pagination();
```

A la página que afecta sería a esta `index.view.php` y donde me dá el error

```
<?php
    for ($i=1; $i <= $n_Page; $i++) {
      if ($page == $i) {
        echo "  <li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='?page=$i'>$i</a></li>";
      }else{
        echo "<li><a href='?page=$i'>$i</a></li>";
      }
    }


?>
```

no entiendo la razñon del error, probablemente esté algo oxidado, alguna sugerencia?

Comment: El problema que tienes está en esta línea: `$articles = $articles->get_articles($page);` y no tiene nada que ver con la pregunta que han marcado como duplicada. Si se reabre la pregunta redacto una respuesta indicando qué te ocurre.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo lo mas probable es que este accediendo mal al metodo fetch que devuelve pdo.

```
fetch()['total'];
```

Tienes que fetch devuelve todo lo que tengas en tu base de tados por medio de la consulta especificando como quieres que te la devuelva, ejemplo un objeto, un array asociativo, ademas fetch se usa Con pdo no con mysqli::query